# Populating user home directory in JupyterHub

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to populate the home directory of the user on JupyterHub. I've followed the Zero to JupyterHub with Kubernetes guide and have a working cluster. I have the folders I want to copy in the container but I'm not sure how to copy them so that they're available to the user.

```
lifecycleHooks:
  postStart:
  exec:
    command: ["cp", "-a", "mydir", "/home/jovyan/mydir"]
```

When I get a shell in my container the folders are there in `/home/jovyan` but when the exec hook runs these folders can't be found. I know I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best way is to copy the folders you need over to a directory other than `/home/jovyan` such as `/tmp` and then copy them from there.

I now have something like this in my `config.yaml` which allows running of multiple commands separated by a semi-colon

```
lifecycleHooks:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command:
          - "sh"
          - "-c"
          - >
            cp -r /tmp/folder_a /home/jovyan;
            cp -r /tmp/folder_b /home/jovyan
```